# Issue in updating elastic search field

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, updating

This how my result source looks like.

```json
{"_source": {"Name": "Where's My Crown Angry birds 3","movie_id":69}}
```

I need to update the Name field as "'Where's My Crown'". I used the following query:

```json
{"script": {"inline": "ctx._source.Name='Where's My Crown'","lang": "painless"},"query": {"match": {"movie_id": 69}}}
```

But I got this error:

```json
{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': "unexpected token ['s'] was expecting one of [{<EOF>, ';'}]."}**
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the fact that there is a single quote in "Where's My Crown" and that interferes with the single quotes around the whole string.

Consider doing it like this (using `params`) instead:

```
{  
   "script": {
       "inline": "ctx._source.Name = params.newName",
       "params": {
         "newName": "Where's My Crown"
       },
       "lang": "painless"
   },
   "query": {"match": {"movie_id": 69}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution below and it also worked for me:

Replace
`'Where's My Crown'`
with
`\"Where's My Crown\"`

So in my case (in JavaScript, not Python, but I think it would work similarly):

```js
const script = Object.entries(newBody).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => {
  return `${prev} ctx._source.${key}=\"${value}\";`;
}, '');
```